Issues Configuring Swap and Moving /home to a New Encrypted Disk on Ubuntu 24.04
I have Ubuntu 24.04 installed with the default disk partitioning settings chosen by the installer, including LVM encryption. I have two SSDs:
First disk with the following partitions:

/boot/efi
/boot
/

Second disk (/dev/sda)
My goal is to:

Allocate a 20GB swap partition from the first disk, which is
encrypted, and activate it. Format the second disk to Ext4, encrypt
it, add it to LVM, and move the /home partition to this disk.

Issue:

After rebooting, the system prompted for the decryption password (same
password for both partitions), attempted to load the system, but then
dropped to a initramfs with alert: "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist". I noticed that the fstab and crypttab files were
empty. Manually filling them didn't resolve the issue.

Question:

How can I properly configure the swap partition and move /home to the
second encrypted disk without causing boot issues? What steps might I
be missing or doing incorrectly?

Here are the steps I performed from a LiveCD environment:
Adding Swap:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pvs
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgs
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvs
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /target/boot/efi
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /target/boot
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /target/*
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /target
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 95G
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvreduce -L 95G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvcreate -L 20G -n swap_1 ubuntu-vg
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkswap /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo swapon /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
#Added line: /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1 none swap sw 0 0

Working with the Second Disk:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda1 sda1_crypt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pvcreate /dev/mapper/sda1_crypt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/mapper/sda1_crypt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/mapper/sda1_crypt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgscan
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgchange -ay
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/mapper/sda1_crypt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvdisplay /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgscan --mknodes
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep -i "allow_mixed_block_sizes" | grep -v "#"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo nano /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
# Find allow_mixed_block_sizes and set it to 1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/mapper/sda1_crypt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvcreate -L 476.9G -n home ubuntu-vg
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/ubuntu-vg/home
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/home /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo rsync -aXS /home/. /mnt/.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
# Added line: /dev/ubuntu-vg/home /home ext4 defaults 0 0
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -a


I have found the hack that helps me and fix my problem
Link to same problem
To make /etc/crypttab available as /cryptroot/crypttab in initramfs, create the following script in the /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks directory and make it executable:
#!/bin/sh
cp /etc/crypttab "${DESTDIR}/cryptroot/crypttab"
exit 0

